# How do I set up code coverage in C++ googletest project in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, code-coverage, googletest

I have a C++ googletest project building in Visual Studio 2010 professional. This builds a console application which generates XML test result output. How can I set it up to get code coverage information?

I have tried instructions [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phuene/archive/2007/05/14/code-coverage-collection.aspx) to instrument the code but viewing the Code Coverage results seems to require Visual Studio Ultimate. Is there any converter for the .coverage files Visual Studio generates?

Bonus points for portable/free/open-source solutions!

Answer (score 13):

You can try OpenCppCoverage: http://opencppcoverage.codeplex.com.

OpenCppCoverage is a code coverage tools for C++ under Windows. It is open-source and works well with google test / Visual Studio C++.

Disclaimer: I am the author of this tool.

Hope that help.

**Edit to follow [brasofilo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1287812/brasofilo) advice:**

To be more precise about your question, OpenCppCoverage should work with Visual Studio C++ 2010 professional. The only requirement is to support **native** Pdb files (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd4f8bd1%28vs.71%29.aspx).

It is open source and free and you can find sources here: https://opencppcoverage.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest.

What do you mean by portable?

- If you mean "Multi platform" -> No, it works only on Windows
- If you mean "Portable application" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_application): OpenCppCoverage required only Redistributable for Visual Studio 2013 to be installed on host (http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=40784) but it does not write to registry and you can move the binaries where you want (usb key for example).

Hope that help.

Comment: Please, tailor each answer according to the question in question, copy pasting the same answer around won't cut it, disclaimer or not disclaimer.

Comment: @OpenCppCoverage Great to see that your project is still alive - last update 4 days ago. I notice that you have a command line interface - could the tool be used by Windows coders who do not use MSVC and still generate HML output? Is it FOSS? Could it be rebuilt for use on Linux? Is it based primarily on `gcov` (and maybe `lcov`) and just re-wrapped as an MSVC plugin? Any plans for a Linux version, or objections to a fork if it is FOSS?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the VSTEST.Consol.exe for this purpose http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj155796.aspx.
 According to documentation, it would run tests written against any test framework. You may enable the 
`/Enablecodecoverage` option, which `Enables data diagnostic adapter CodeCoverage in the test run.`

More information may be found here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bhuvaneshwari/archive/2012/06/16/vstest-console-exe-commandline-test-runner.aspx

There is also an open source code coverage tool called ggcov: http://ggcov.sourceforge.net/index.html

Hope that these helps.

Comment: Looks like VSTest.Console.exe comes with Visual Studio 2012; I am still on 2010.

Comment: @PsZk No, it comes with VS2010 too. according to this link:http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vststest/thread/6b9c5303-2c0d-4790-9552-cee3eef6df0c/